# Toggle button changing another div ID

Tags: toggle

I'm new here and after learning js i create this monster:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$("#guzik").click(function () {
    $("#red").attr('id', ($("#red").attr('id') === 'blue' ? 'red' : 'blue'));
});
});//]]>  

</script>
```

guzik is my button that I want it to change another div with id #red to #blue (toggling) Where are my mistakes? :)

Answer (score 0):

Better way is changing class instead of ID

```js
$("#guzik").click(function () {
    $("#div").toggleClass('red blue');
});
```

```css
.red {background:red}
.blue {background:blue}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="guzik">GUZIK</a>
<div id="div" class="blue">CONTENT</div>
```